# Getting error in serverless deploy - AWS Lambda Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, serverless

I'm getting below error while running the command "serverless deploy"

```
   SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
   node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-acm\dist-cjs\ACMClient.js:28
           const _config_8 = (0, runtimeExtensions_1.resolveRuntimeExtensions)(_config_7, configuration?.extensions || []);
                                                                                                        ^
```

Can you help me what can be cause of this